# создание msi установщика

Tags: wix, msi

я хочу сделать msi установщик в которой я смогу вложить 2 exe файла. они распакуются и запустятся. Проблема в том что начинается бесконечная установка*
использую wix toolset

```
<?define name = "testss"?>
<?define silentArgs = ""?>
<?define version = "1.0.0"?>
<?define publisher = "cat"?>
<?define guid = "53bd6b32-7d0b-487b-a1df-5484f88d7082"?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">

  <Package Name="$(var.name)" Manufacturer="$(var.publisher)" Version="$(var.version)"
          UpgradeCode="$(var.guid)" Scope="perMachine">

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="setup.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="InstallFeature" Title="Install Feature">
      <ComponentRef Id="file1" />
      <ComponentRef Id="file2" />
    </Feature>

    <CustomAction Id="run_exe" Return="asyncWait" Execute="commit"
                  ExeCommand="$(var.silentArgs)" HideTarget="yes" Impersonate="no"
                  FileRef="executable" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="run_exe" After="InstallFiles"
              Condition="NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="$(var.guid)">


          <Component Id="file1" DiskId="1">
            <File Id="executable1" Name="test1.exe"
                  Source="C:\asd\test1.exe" />
          </Component>

          <Component Id="file2" DiskId="1">
            <File Id="executable2" Name="test2.exe"
                  Source="C:\asd\test2.exe" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Package>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Можете попробовать "Inno Setup" https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php на мой взгляд в ней более простое создание инсталляторов с помощью макросов.